# Error while installing Scrapy: path not specified

Tags: python, scrapy

I recently found out that scrapy is a great library for scraping so i tried to install scrapy on my machine, but when i tried to do `pip install scrapy` it installed for a while and threw me this error..

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools
```

and

```
error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 is required. Get it with "Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools": http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools

    ----------------------------------------
Command "d:\pycharmprojects\environments\scrapyenv\scripts\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-build-arbeqlly\\Twisted\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-jdj93131-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile --install-headers d:\pycharmprojects\environments\scrapyenv\include\site\python3.5\Twisted" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-arbeqlly\Twisted\
```

So after that I went to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/#build-tools-for-visual-studio-2017) website and installed the tools for python..

but getting this at the end of installing:

```
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.misc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.bugfix' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.doc' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.feature' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*.removal' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'NEWS' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'README' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files matching 'topfiles' found under directory 'src\twisted'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\CREDITS'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'src\twisted\topfiles\ChangeLog.Old'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'codecov.yml'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'appveyor.yml'
no previously-included directories found matching 'bin'
no previously-included directories found matching 'admin'
no previously-included directories found matching '.travis'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'docs\historic\2003'
warning: no previously-included files matching '*' found under directory 'docs\historic\2003'
error: Setup script exited with error: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: 'C:\\Program Files\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\BuildTools\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.10.25017\\PlatformSDK\\lib'
```

any help?

Answer (score 2):

Scrapy docs now recommend using [Conda](https://conda.io/miniconda) for Windows installation:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/install.html#windows

Comment: thanks ! i downloaded the whole build tools and now it works from [here](http://landinghub.visualstudio.com/visual-cpp-build-tools)

Answer (score 1):

This error comes up when you don't have Windows SDK installed.

When you used Build Tools or Visual Studio to compile, often you need both the C++ compiler and Windows SDK. In the Build Tools, there is a "Custom" installation option which enables you to select to install both C++ and Windows SDK. In Visual Studio, you have to modify your installation to install Windows SDK.

I *believe* you need the SDK corresponding to the the platform you are using (Windows 10 SDK for Windows 10, etc).